# How to check which tasks are still running in a SLURM batch job?

Tags: slurm

When scheduling a batch job in SLURM, e.g.

```
sbatch -N 10 batch-script.sh
```

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --job-name=jobname

srun --label /usr/bin/hostname
```

it is possible to check which step is currently running with `sacct`:

```
       JobID    JobName  Partition    Account  AllocCPUS      State ExitCode
------------ ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- --------
...
421.1        hostname                  test         10    RUNNING      0:0
```

But how can one check which tasks/nodes are still running in the current step and which have finished? (In this case there's only 1 task per node.) The only option I found in the docs is to set a `--task-epilog` command and log something when each task is done.

It would be great to see, for example, that 8 out of 10 nodes have finished their task, and `node03` and `node08` are still running theirs.

Answer (score 4):

You can see which nodes are active with the `squeue` command. To filter for only your jobs you can do `squeue -u [yourname]`. To always keep updating you can do `watch -n 1 "squeue -u [yourname]"`.

Comment: Thanks, but I think that `squeue` shows nodes that are allocated for the current step, and they are not released until the whole step is done. At least that's what I see in practice.

Comment: Hmm... I am afraid I have no experience then with your problem, good luck!